# C++ representation of C# ? modifier on CLR

Tags: clr

I'm making class library running on CLR .

I am wondering how I should code functions which return nullable type.

How can I make C++ ref class that works exactly same like the C# class below?

I searched on MSDN already, but i can't find anymore.

```
class ResultClass
{
}

class SomeClass
{
    public ResultClass? getResult();
}
```

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++/CLI doesn't support the syntax sugar with the ? question mark, you have to use the Nullable<> struct explicitly.  It otherwise has the same usage as C#, you *never* use Nullable<> on a reference type.  Just return `nullptr` for a reference type like ResultClass.  A snippet that shows syntax:

```
public ref class SomeClass {
public:
    ResultClass^ getResult() {
       return nullptr;    // TODO: call native code
    }
    Nullable<int> nullableExample() {
       Nullable<int> retval;
       if (someCondition) retval = Nullable<int>(42);
       return retval;
    }
};
```